# Can oscillating "multi-tools" sand vertical surfaces?

Tags: tools, sanding

I need to sand some rough spots on our old front door before repainting and am considering buying/using a multi-tool for this task (as well as some tricky flooring and drywall tasks later).

What's strange though, is that I haven't seen any demonstration videos where people are sanding a vertical surface. Do these tools require the surfaces to be flat and horizontal when sanding?

Comment: Your arm is going to get wicked tired holding up a heavy sander for any period of time!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're talking about tools like [this](http://www.harborfreight.com/oscillating-multifunction-power-tool-68303.html), then you **can** use them vertically.

[image: Picture of tool]

The [manual](http://manuals.harborfreight.com/manuals/68000-68999/68303.pdf) for the tool I linked to doesn't have any mention of the words *horizontal*, *vertical*, *level*, *flat* or *upright*, so if they don't warn you not to, you can assume it's OK to do it.

One thing to note is that to sand a vertical surface, you're going to have to hold the tool more tightly than you would if you were working on a horizontal surface.  This will cause more vibration to be transferred to your hand and wrists, which will tire them out more quickly.  If you're doing a large area, this can cause repetitive strain injury; when I sanded some window frames a while back, it took a couple of days afterwards for my wrist to feel OK again.

Comment: Excellent.  That's what I needed to know

Comment: Link to the tool on harborfreight.com is `404 Not Found`, maybe a picture would be better.

Answer (score 2):

That is odd, I've never noticed that but you're right!  Anyway, they can sand, cut, or whatever else you want to do in any orientation.

I've been thrilled with [mine](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001EYUGMI) so far.